# Can't figure out grammar tweak

Tags: antlr4

I'm trying to build a v4 grammar for an existing DSL, and am a bit out of my depth.  I've tried everything I could think with no luck.  We can have a function call like `foo(param1, param2);`, which I have working.  There is an optional construct like `foo(y, z) x 100;` which means to call the fx 100 times (the x is the literal token, great choice eh!)  That's what I can't get to work.

My func_call now looks like this: `func_call: Identifier '(' arg_list ')';`

Adding a `(('x'|'X') expr)?` and variations thereof didn't work.  It starts to get confused by variables named x.

If it helps, an old yacc grammar for this language had this: `rep: func_call REP expr;` (where REP is x)  Any help would be appreciated.  thanks!

Comment: What does your lexer rule for variables look like? In your DSL, is `x` a valid variable?

Comment: @hendryau: here is what my identifiers are defined as: `Identifier: ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'_') ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'_'|'0'..'9')*;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make `Identifier` a parser rule rather than a lexer rule. This way, the lexer always matches `x` as a `Rep`, even if it is contained in `identifier`. Here is one solution:

```
grammar Foo;

func_call : identifier '(' arg_list? ')' (Rep expr)? ;
arg_list : identifier (',' identifier)* ;
expr : //TODO implement
     ;

identifier :  idFront (idFront | Digit)* ;
idFront : Rep | OtherThanRep | '_' ;

Digit : [0-9] ;
Rep : 'x' | 'X';
OtherThanRep : [a-wA-W] | 'y' | 'z' | 'Y' | 'Z' ;

WS : [ \t\f\r\n] ->skip;
```

The generated parser successfully parses `x(x,x) x 100`

[image]

Comment: awesome!  thanks so much, that appears to have worked